# How to keep punctuation in typedDependencies?

Tags: stanford-nlp

```
ChineseGrammaticalStructure gs = new ChineseGrammaticalStructure(t);
Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
```

I have tried to print gs and tdl, gs keeps the punctuation while tdl lost it. How to keep punctuation while convert GrammaticalStructure to typedDependencies when using stanford parser 3.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

It seems stanford parser is hard to deal with this question, people who have the same question may try corenlp.